# Server Redirect with RedirectToAction from HttpPost with Ajax jQuery call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

1. Using Ajax jQuery call, we are calling HttpPost ASP.NET MVC controller Action method.
2. HttpPost MVC controller need to do server side transfer so using RedirectToAction. Its a complete new page, which should be transferred.

However the page is not getting loaded. We dont want to use Windows.Location.Href. Without using Windows.Location.Href , can we do server transfer to new page in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: If you want to transfer the page after making a request AJAX is pointless. The whole point of AJAX is to ***not*** transfer the page when making a reuest

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Ajax calls **never** redirect. If you want to redirect, make a normal submit - do **not** use ajax

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is:

1. Not possible
2. Not necessary

If you really want to use AJAX to complete the post operation then when that is successful transfer to a different page you will have to use `window.location.href`.

However, as pointed out by Rory and Stephen in the comments this is not really a typical use case for AJAX. You would normally use AJAX to perform and action and update the page without redirecting the user.

Seeing as how you do want to redirect the user why not remove the AJAX and just allow the form to POST back to the server. Then in your server side code your can return a `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: Completely agree ajax calls are for partial page loads and not for loading a new page all together. However we don’t want to go for window.location.href, when using it we are sending some important details by query string. Looked into encrypting or encoding of data. However it’s useless as end users would be able to get the data. Other way is by making a post request as data will be sent by body. So exploring ways of doing server side transfer with ajax jquery call.